# Accessing previous Keys in Array

Tags: php

I want to evaluate a postfix expression using this code.

```
$test = array(1,2,"+",3,"+");    // this condition works
$test = array(1,2,3,"+","+");    // this condition fails
foreach($test as $key=>$val){
    var_dump($test);
    if($val == "+"){
        $test[$key] = $test[$key-1] + $test[$key-2];   //uses previous keys
        unset($test[$key-1]);
        unset($test[$key-2]);
    }
}
```

I'm using the above code but my code fails in this condition.

```
iteration 1
array (size=5)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 2
  2 => int 3
  3 => string '+' (length=1)
  4 => string '+' (length=1)

iteration 2
array (size=3)
  0 => int 1
  3 => int 5
  4 => string '+' (length=1)    // code fails here because key 2 is not available
```

Is there a way I can access the previous keys without having to subtract from present key?
Or a way to reorder the keys after every iteration of the **foreach** loop?

I know I can get previous keys by adding another loop after my **if** condition ends. But I want to do it in a better way, if possible

Comment: Why are you defining $test two times?

Comment: To give you an idea of when the code works and when it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You for `($i=0; $i <count($array); $i++);`  and with `$array[$i - 1]` you can access the previous element.

Here is an example:

```
$cnt = count($test);
for ($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
    echo "current item: " . $test[$i - 1] ."\n";
    if ($i != 0) {
        echo "previous item: " . $test[$i - 1]."\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`prev($array)` should do the trick in a foreach loop.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.prev.php

Do note that this function changes the internal position of the array. Using next, prev, end and reset are the official ways of changing the pointer, it is in fact what foreach uses internally.